# Excel style categories

Tags: excel

Is is possible to manage new style categories in Excel 2010, i.e. rename, delete and create new categories?

I can add a style but no option for category:
ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add Name:="Style 1"

I can delete a style but no option for category:
ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Style 1").Delete

Answer (score 0):

Styles belong to a Workbook object. On screen you will see them grouped into "Themed Cell Styles", "Good, Bad, Neutral", etc. Via the Excel object model we have no access to these "group names", so we can't read or write them.

Best approximation is to read the `.BuiltIn` property, ex.

```
Sub StyleTest()
Dim MyStyle As Style

    Set MyStyle = Range("A1").Style

    If MyStyle.BuiltIn Then
        ' built in style

    Else
        ' custom style

    End If        
End Sub
```

Even when you duplicate a builtin style, the copied style will be created under category "Custom".

Get the name of a style via its `.Name` or `.Value` properties. However this is a read-only property, so renaming a style rather means duplicating a style under a different name and then deleting the original

Duplicating a style really means "creating" a new style and copying all properties from the source style ... piece by piece ... unfortunately!

Modify a style like for example

```
Sub CreateStyle()
Dim MyStyle As Style

    Set MyStyle = ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("Test") ' Note this will fail if style "Test" already exists

    With MyStyle
        .IncludeNumber = True
        .IncludeFont = True
        .IncludeAlignment = True
        .IncludeBorder = True
        .IncludePatterns = True
        .IncludeProtection = False
    End With

    MyStyle.NumberFormat = "#.##0"

    With MyStyle.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .Strikethrough = False
        .ThemeColor = 6
        .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With

    With MyStyle.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = 0
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for the response, very helpful even your confirmation of no access to categories. I work mostly in Word and the issue does not arise as there are no categories. It wouldn't be so quite so bad if they hadn't given the categories silly names. "Good, Bad and Neutral" sounds like a spaghetti Western to me!